# Velocity and acceleration (as vectors) in a straight line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, velocity, vectors, coordinate-systems

A student is trying to determine the acceleration of a feather as she drops it to the ground. If the student is looking to achieve **a positive velocity *and* positive acceleration**, what is the most sensible way to set up her coordinate system?

A) Her hand should be a coordinate of zero and the upward direction should be considered positive.

B) Her hand should be a coordinate of zero and the downward direction should be considered positive.

C) The floor should be a coordinate of zero and the upward direction should be considered positive.

D) The floor should be a coordinate of zero and the downward direction should be considered positive.

**I think, if her hand was the origin, downward should be positive in order for the velocity to be positive, but could anybody describe the acceleration in that instance? And if the floor was the zero-point, what would happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity is downward, and the acceleration is downward. Whatever direction you choose, if you start with a velocity of zero the sign of both will be the same (if you throw the feather down, it will decelerate - so the acceleration will the "up". I don't think that is intended here). Whether the floor or the hand is zero in the coordinate system doesn't change whether velocity and acceleration have a positive sign - only the sense of direction (up or down) can change that.

However, what is "sensible" as far as **origin** of the coordinate system is a matter of opinion. Choosing the hand has the advantage that you start with a velocity of zero at position zero; choosing the floor makes for a more robust coordinate system (less likely to vary from one experiment to the next).